# PHP Code Igniter Server not responding on some requests while Server Sent Event is running

Tags: php, codeigniter, server-sent-events, eventsource

I have this SSE running and sending event to client every 1 second.
The problem is the server stops responding to other client's requests while SSE is running.

```
//client

var time;
var source = new EventSource(url);
source.addEventListener('time', (e)=>{
   time= e.data;
}, false);


//in my controller (CodeIgniter)

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 
while(true){
    echo "id: 12" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "event: time\n";
    echo "data: ".date('F j, Y g:i:s A ', time()). PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;

    ob_flush();
    flush();

    if ( connection_aborted() ) break;

    sleep(1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with session lock. Try adding `session_write_close();` above `sleep(1)` statement